# Angularjs directives not evaluating ~

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a angularjs directive with the html template compiled in the linker function

```
var htmlTemplate = '<img ng-src="~/img/logos/{{account.Logo}}" width="45" height="35" />'

 var linker = function (scope, element) {

    element.html(htmlTemplate).show();
    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
};
```

but the directive is not evaluating the '~' sign in img src to resolve the image path.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to use an absolute URL for your `ng-src` directive like `ng-src="http://example.com/img/logos/{{account.Logo}}"`

Comment: May I ask what it is you are looking for, when you use "~"? If you want an image relative to current page/URL where the directive is used, you can use `img/logos/{{account.Logo}}` directly. Ideally, you should have a logic in your ng-src directive to prefix your app's base URL (http://example.com/).